# How to make filter on page in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I've got array with objects in my component:

```
finalistsCollection = [
    { name: 'Ann' , nomination: 'N1' },
    { name: 'Jack' , nomination: 'N1' },
    { name: 'Morgan', nomination: 'N2' },
    { name: 'Billy', nomination: 'N2' }, 
    { name: 'Monica', nomination: 'N3' },
    { name: 'Rian', nomination: 'N3' },
]
```

And here's html component:

```
<button>Show N1 nomination</button>
<button>Show N2 nomination</button>
<button>Show N3 nomination</button>
<button>Show All</button>

<div *ngFor="let finalist of finalistsCollection">
    <div class="member-block">
      {{finalist.name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I make buttons with filter function in Angular way?

Comment: Sorry, your question isn't clear. What exactly are you expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to see some basic tutorial for Angular.

First you need to add click method for button and pass nomination value, which you want to filter:

```
<button (click)="filterData('N1')">Show N1 nomination</button>
<button (click)="filterData('N2')">Show N2 nomination</button>
<button (click)="filterData('N3')">Show N3 nomination</button>
<button (click)="filterData()">Show All</button>
<div *ngFor="let finalist of filteredCollection">
 <div class="member-block">
    {{finalist.name}}
 </div>
</div>
```

and then add your filterData method in component
     
    `filteredCollection = [];
    filterData(nomination: string = null) {
     if (nomination) {
       this.filteredCollection = this.finalistsCollection.filter(
        x => x.nomination == nomination
      );
     } else {
       this.filteredCollection = this.finalistsCollection;
     }
    }`

Here is working example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-arrayfilter-example

Answer (score 2):

```
<button (click)="filter('N1')">Show N1 nomination</button>
<button (click)="filter('N2')">Show N2 nomination</button>
<button (click)="filter('N3')">Show N3 nomination</button>
<button (click)="filter('')">Show All</button>

<div *ngFor="let finalist of finalistsCollections">
    <div class="member-block">
      {{finalist.name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

in ts:

```
    filter(search){
if(search!==''){
    this.finalistsCollections=this.finalistsCollection.filter(q=> q.nomination.indexOf(search) > -1);
}else{
this.finalistsCollections=this.finalistsCollection;
}
    }
```

and in the ngOnInit set

```
this.finalistsCollections=this.finalistsCollection;
```